# Ubuntu 20.04 won't let deb files to update applications

Tags: apt, package-management

Installing apps with a `.deb` is quite easy, but then there's an update to the same application, I download the new `.deb` file, execute the file will take me to the application's page in "Ubuntu Software", but it won't let me update the application, I have to uninstall and then install it again.

Same with auto updates on most applications (Google Chrome, Visual Studio Code, etc..). With every update I need to uninstall and install again.

Are there any settings that would allow me to update applications like Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: You can always upgrade a package using CLI. If you install a new deb using `apt` or `dpkg`, it will upgrade it. But e.g. Google Chrome doesn't require manual upgrading by downloading a new deb. When you install it the first time it adds a repository that allows to upgrade automatically.

Comment: Can you give specific example of a deb file that does not let you update?

Comment: `visual studio code` and `git kraken` are the biggest offenders for me particularly. Both will have released updated very often

Answer (score 1):

Snap packages are updated automatically in the background or by running `sudo snap refresh` Visual Studio Code and Git Kraken are packaged as snap packages in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install the Visual Studio Code and Git Kraken snap packages open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
sudo snap install gitkraken --classic
```